# Chef MySQL cookbook user creation error

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm using https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mysql to install mysql on Oracle Linux. Getting error when creating user="mysql".
Here is the error:

```
  ×  xccdf_org.cisecurity.benchmarks_rule_7.2_Disable_System_Accounts: Disable System Accounts (1 failed)
     ✔  /etc/passwd with user =~ /^(?!root|sync|shutdown|halt|oemagent|epg_vcac|MWadm|MWwls|apache|[+-]@).*$/ entries should not be empty
     ×  /etc/passwd with user =~ /^(?!root|sync|shutdown|halt|oemagent|epg_vcac|MWadm|MWwls|apache|[+-]@).*$/ uid to_i < 500 shell != "/sbin/nologin" entries should be empty
     expected `[#<struct user="mysql", password="x", uid="27", gid="27", desc="MySQL Server", home="/var/lib/mysql", shell="/bin/bash", count=nil, usernames=nil, username=nil, content=nil>].empty?` to return true, got false
```

My recipe:

```
mysql_service 'default' do
  version node[:mysql][:version]
  bind_address '0.0.0.0'
  port '3306'
  data_dir node[:mysql][:data_dir]
  error_log node[:mysql][:log_dir]
  initial_root_password node[:mysql][:password]
  action [:create, :start]
end
```

What am i missing?

Comment: How do you exactly create the user? Error looks like from some kind of validator.

Comment: I assume chef creates the user.

Comment: It is not a output from pasted resource. How do you run your chef-client?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the community cookbook i was using creates a normal user "MySQL", I need to change it to a service user to pass our company's security scan.